# Good way to handle multiple activity flows in an Android app

Tags: java, android

I am currently building an Android application. My application is somewhat dynamic in nature in a sense that users are able to experience multiple activity flows based on a set of boolean variables stored within the application. Here are some examples of what I mean:

Let `A, B, C, D, E` be different activities in my application and `flag1, flag2, flag3` be difference boolean variables.

`if flag1 is true
activity flow: 
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
back navigation:
A <- C <- D`

`if flag2 is true
activity flow: 
B -> C -> D
back navigation:
B <- C <- D`

`if flag3 is true
activity flow: 
A -> D -> E
back navigation:
A <- E`

`if flag3 is false
activity flow: 
D -> E
backstack:
A <- E`

My application consists of quite a number of if/else conditions just to handle the forward and backward activity changes in each activity by calling the `startActivity()` method. Is there a better way to manage this activity flow? Like by creating a custom stack or an `ArrayList<Activity>` for instance.

Comment: Way too broad to be answered. It's like architecture design.

Comment: I would suggest you go through the new navigation architecture that google announced. It is quite intuitive. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/